# Bash file for moving files

Tags: linux, bash, command, line

I want to move a file which has extension .png and.jpg
I tried:

```
mv ~/folder/*.png  ~/folder/folder2
```

Is there a way I can do multiple file types on one line like the following? (I tried this but it is not valid clearly)

```
mv ~/folder/*.png&&*jpg  ~/folder/folder2
```

I know I can just write two lines but I would like to be less verbose if possible.

Comment: `*.@(png|jpg|jpeg|pdf|mp3|mp4)` with `extglob` enabled `shopt -s extglob` and probably `nullglob`

Comment: `mv ~/folder/*.{png,jpg} ~/folder/fold2`

Comment: @Jetchisel `globstar` isn't need, just use brace expansion.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: @Barmar, yes I meant `extglob` thank you for that wonderful comment

Comment: @Jetchisel You don't need extglob for brace expansion.

Comment: @Barmar I'm not using any braces. I mean my example does not.

Comment: @Jetchisel I use braces on my Mac running 3.2. I've been using it for decades.

Comment: Still need a `nullglob` at least in bash, regardless if you use brace expansion or extglob.

Comment: BTW, I always recommend using `mv -i` or `mv -n`, for bulk/automated moves like this, because without the `-i` or `-n` options, if there's a naming conflict it'll silently and irreversibly delete some of the conflicting files.

Comment: Thanks guys I am a programmer so I wasn't sure if this was the right place or not. I appreciate all the help. I will direct any future questions to Unix & Linux.

Answer (score 2):

In bash, zsh and ksh you can `mv *.{png,jpg} folder2`. This won't work in the classic Bourne shell, though.

Answer (score 2):

A general solution uses [brace expansion](https://wiki-dev.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/brace):

```
mv ~/folder/*.{png,jpg} ~/folder/folder2
```

Prior to passing the arguments to `mv`, Bash will expand this to:

```
mv ~/folder/*.png ~/folder/*.jpg ~/folder/folder2
```

...which should do what you want.

(Footnote: as JMW points out, Bash is also responsible for expanding the `*.whatever` globs into a series of filenames, so in reality `mv` is receiving an argument list like `~/folder/1.png ~/folder/2.png ~/folder/3.jpg ~/folder/folder2`. Brace expansion and globbing are among several parsing steps Bash takes before sending the arguments to whatever program you're calling.)

Comment: Actually those asterisks get expanded as well into a series of matching files that are passed as arguments to mv, except in the case where there are no matches, in which case the literal asterisks may get passed instead. It might not matter that much most of the time, but it's worth being clear that those asterisks are expanded by the shell and not mv. People who are new to shell could get confused. It gets even more confusing when dealing with tools like find that interpret asterisks as wildcards when they are passed literally by the shell.